# Exception during XML rendering

Tags: android, xml, exception

Exception raised during rendering: Index: 0, Size: 0

Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

I don't know how to see the Error Log, couldn't find it. I'm sure that the error is in that Spinner:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerRacaAnimaisAddEdit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_slim_spinner"
    android:prompt="@string/escolher_raca_prompt"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
```

I'm using API 11 min and 19 max and the background of the spinner is a .9, I put the .9 files in all the drawable folders with the respectives sizes. I used a website to convert the size of the .9. I don't know what is wrong.

EDIT:

I found the Error Log in Help > About > Installation Details > Tab Configuration > View Error Log

And here is it:

```
!MESSAGE activity_atendimento_add_edit.xml: Index: 0, Size: 0
!STACK 0
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ninepatch.NinePatchChunk.draw(NinePatchChunk.java:157)
    at com.android.ninepatch.NinePatchChunk.draw(NinePatchChunk.java:101)
    at android.graphics.NinePatch_Delegate$1.draw(NinePatch_Delegate.java:242)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.GcSnapshot.drawInLayer(GcSnapshot.java:613)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.GcSnapshot.draw(GcSnapshot.java:583)
    at android.graphics.NinePatch_Delegate.draw(NinePatch_Delegate.java:239)
    at android.graphics.NinePatch_Delegate.nativeDraw(NinePatch_Delegate.java:187)
    at android.graphics.NinePatch.nativeDraw(NinePatch.java)
    at android.graphics.NinePatch.drawSoftware(NinePatch.java:172)
    at android.graphics.Canvas.drawPatch(Canvas.java:1103)
    at android.graphics.NinePatch.draw(NinePatch.java:163)
    at android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable.draw(NinePatchDrawable.java:229)
    at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.draw(DrawableContainer.java:70)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14450)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14350)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14350)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14348)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14574)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1603)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14350)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14350)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14348)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14350)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:584)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:338)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:517)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1584)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1309)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.PreviewIconFactory.render(PreviewIconFactory.java:368)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.PreviewIconFactory.initColors(PreviewIconFactory.java:595)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.PreviewIconFactory.getBackgroundColor(PreviewIconFactory.java:570)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.PaletteControl.reloadPalette(PaletteControl.java:437)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.reloadPalette(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1327)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.changed(GraphicalEditorPart.java:771)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationChooser.onDeviceChange(ConfigurationChooser.java:1411)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.DeviceMenuListener.widgetSelected(DeviceMenuListener.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

How can I solve it so I can use my Graphical Layout in Eclipse with no problems? Every Spinner in my app is causing this, but not the ones with an array_string.

Comment: It isn't with your spinner xml, it is that you are trying to set a spinner to an empty list; so when it tries to create the initial spinner view based on the index value, it can't because that index value doesn't exist.

Comment: @zgc7009, I think I understood, but I'm setting an adapter in that spinner. When I run the app in my smartphone it works fine, but not when I try to view the xml in graphical layout tab. How can I solve it?

Comment: Check that you are using the correct API level for rendering. In Eclipse it is at the top next to the little droid

Comment: @codeMagic In my android manifest is: 
android:minSdkVersion="11"
android:targetSdkVersion="19"

And I'm using API 19 at the API level rendering.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project? I'm not sure if it will help or not. I've seen this before but can't remember the cause.

Comment: @Jonas452 I don't usually mess with the graphical layout stuff, since Eclipse had done a really bad job implementing it when I started out. Is the editor not showing the spinner itself, or not showing anything contained in the spinner?

Comment: @codeMagic didn't work.

Comment: @zgc7009 Nothing is been shown, but when I take out that spinner I can see my screen.

Comment: The graphical editor may just not be able to populate the spinner, if it works in your application I would consider it good.

Comment: @zgc7009 It works, but I would like to see my screen at the Eclipse, so I could do some changes.

Comment: @Jonas452 unfortunately the graphical editor can only do but so much, thus likely excludes prepopulatiin your spinner so you are just going to have to test it out on an actual device or emulator.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the .9 images that I was using in my spinners. I put all of them in drawable-SOMETHINGdpi folders, but that was wrong, so I put the .9 images in the drawable default folder and everything is ok now.